# [react and Material-UI]: Appbar(NavBar) not picking material ui css

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui, react-navigation, appbar

I just want to create a simple Nav bar using Material-UI. but unfortunately, it's not working. The method mentioned in the docs, consist of a lot of extra code which I do not need. Wondering if it's possible to achieve the same without all that code.

[image: this is what I am getting]

these are the list of dependencies installed in 'package.json'

```
"dependencies": {
"@material-ui/core": "^3.9.2",
"react": "^16.8.3",
"react-dom": "^16.8.3",
"react-redux": "^6.0.1",
"react-router-dom": "^4.3.1",
"react-scripts": "2.1.5",
"redux": "^4.0.1"
```

},

this is my `navbar component`

```
import React from 'react'
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';

const Navbar = () => {
    return(
        <div>
            <nav className="nav-wrapper">
                <div className="container">
                    <Link to="/" className="brand-logo">Shopping</Link>

                    <ul className="right">
                        <li><Link to="/">Shop</Link></li>
                        <li><Link to="/cart">My cart</Link></li>
                        <li><Link to="/cart"><i className="material-icons">shopping_cart</i></Link></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </nav>
        </div>
    )
}
export default Navbar;
```

and this is my 'App.js'

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Navbar from './components/Navbar';
import {BrowserRouter, Route, Switch} from 'react-router-dom'
import Home from './components/Home'
import Cart from './components/Cart'

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <BrowserRouter>
        <div className="App">

          <Navbar/>
            <Switch>
                <Route exact path="/" component={Home}/>
                <Route path="/cart" component={Cart}/>
              </Switch>
        </div>
      </BrowserRouter>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Comment: I don’t see anything in the code that you shared that is using material-ui. It isn’t clear what your expected results are or what “extra” code from the examples you are trying to avoid.

Comment: Material-UI doesn’t automatically add any CSS to html elements. You have to use Material-UI components in order to bring Material-UI CSS into play.

Comment: @RyanCogswell I am following this article https://medium.com/@ayabellazreg/make-a-simple-shopping-cart-app-using-react-redux-1-3-fefde93e80c7 and the author is using material-ui cdn with same markup as mine and the author is getting a responsive layout.

Comment: this is what I intend to achieve.

Comment: That article is using [Materialize](https://materializecss.com/getting-started.html), not [Material-UI](https://material-ui.com/). They are not related aside from being two very different ways of producing looks based on Google's [Material Design](https://material.io/design/).

Comment: oh my bad. thanks for pointing that out.